# Would the aggressive use of an uninstaller tool be equivalent to a fresh install of the OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall, windows-installation, revo-uninstaller

I would like to speed up a slow Dell Inspiron 1545 running Windows 7. It is something like 5 years old with the original OS installation on it.

I know that reinstalling the OS would do the trick but I would like to avoid the endless Windows update that would follow (I have no access to a slipstreamed version of the OS).

Would an alternative be to use a tool like the Revo Uninstaller and delete everything I can?

Comment: It might make things faster but it sure is not the same as a new install. There are probably plenty of entries left after that that would not be present with a clean reinstall. On the other hand the danger is that keys are deleted with "aggressive" methods that are needed by the system. Why not use one of those "Update packs" that have all updates up to a single point in one installer if you do not like windows update?

Comment: Tool like `Revo Uninstaller` are snake oil just like registery cleaners.  Tools like `Revo Uninstaller` specifically do EXACTLY what Add/Remove Programs does, run the uninstaller procedure, for the installed program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only uninstalling will not help speeding up the computer. There are few other things you can try which might help speeding up the old machine.

1. Update all the device drivers to the latest one available on the Internet.
2. Perform a **Disk Cleanup** on the drive containing the OS, that is your **C:** drive.
3. Do a **Disk Defragmentation** using the **Disk Defragmenter** program that is available on Windows. Or you can try out other free defragmentation tools that are available on the Internet.
4. Run **msconfig** and disable unwanted Services and Startup Items.
5. Uninstall all those unwanted programs. You can do this without Revo.